# Ask Apache to treat a zip file (or tar.gz, tar.bz2, etc) as a directory?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

Is it possible to make Apache to treat zip files and other archive files as directories in some certain directories?

Comment: You could fuse-mount the archive, but what are you trying to achieve? Making Apache read data from an archive will not automatically compress the outgoing data.

Comment: @KenSharp I'm just seeking for a way to conveniently upload files. It's not for productive usage, so performance does not matter here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be this older apache module (no idea if it still works with current apache versions):
http://modzipread.sourceforge.net/

Is using PHP an option? PHP includes a library for opening ZIP files by default: http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php
I'm sure that there are several sample zip browsers floating around

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, php is acceptable. Can you give a code snippet to acheive it in php?

Comment: @xuhdev If you click on the link Dominik R gave you, there is a whole page with lots of examples.